# Paginación de una tabla muy larga (Angular + .Net)

Tags: .net, angular, paginación

Les explico: esta duda trata sobre el tipo más "correcto" de paginación en una tabla.

Cuando tienes una vista con una tabla muy larga, la gente suele dividirla en varias páginas con un script, que te las va paginando según el número de filas que tiene la tabla. Sin embargo, esto lo que suele hacer por dentro es una llamada a un servicio que te trae todas las filas y luego se van paginando de golpe.

Esto está muy bien para un script de vistas de tablas que no vayan a ser muy largas pero... ¿y si la tabla tiene 84000 filas? No es lo más idóneo traerse esas 84000 filas de golpe y que el script las pagine, lo más inteligente sería poder realizar una llamada al servicio que se trajese una sección de la tabla, y al clickar en siguiente por ejemplo, se liste la siguiente sección, y así sucesivamente...

Por lo tanto me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma convencional para realizar dicha paginación desde el back-end por ejemplo, y conocer el consejo de alguien más veterano que yo a la hora de diseñar dicha lógica, muchas gracias a todos y un saludo.

[image: Aquí un ejemplo de a lo que me refiero, no vaya a ser que no se me entienda bien]

Comment: Yo tengo esa misma duda que expone Cesar, en esta explicación que da Raúl sobre cómo lo hace, según lo que entendí, no puedes usar un paginador como el que marca Cesar en la imagen, porque en el ejemplo de Raúl te traes la cantidad exacta de páginas que muestras desde la base, ej: de 10 en 10, para que el frontend te pagine tiene que tener el total a paginar y de ahí te calcula y pagina.

Comment: He visto en algunas páginas de muchos registros, te ponen al final puntos suspensivos (...), Ud. puede darle click a los puntos y en ese momento el aplicativo carga el siguiente bloque de datos digamos de 100 registros de la base, y el script vuelve a paginar desde la ultima página mostrada.

Sería bueno si alguien explicara como hacerlo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola César yo lo que hacía para limitar las búsquedas como tu explicas es de la siguiente forma.

---

### Lógica del procedimiento

Pongamos por ejemplo que tienes un límite de mostrado de 10 elementos.

Si estamos en la página 1, las filas irían de la 0 a la número 10.

Si estamos en la página 2, las filas irían de la 10 a la 20.
Y así sucesivamente.

Entonces tenemos 2 parámetros el límite de datos que quieres devolver y el último número de filas consultado.

Vamos a llamarlos **offset** y **limit**

```
offset = (page-1)*limit
```

Ejemplo página 1

Nos trae los 10 primeros datos desde la fila 0

```
offset = (1-1)*10
offset = 0
```

Ejemplo página 2

Nos trae los 10 siguientes datos después de las 10 primeras filas

```
offset = (2-1)*10
offset = 10
```

---

### Envío de datos

Para enviar los datos a tu controlador tendrías que hacer algo así.

Ejemplo página 1

```
www.example.com?offset=0&limit=10
```

Ejemplo página 2

```
www.example.com?offset=10&limit=10
```

Estos parámetros luego se lo pasas a la consulta sql para realizar las consiguientes operaciones.

---

### Tratamiento de parámetros en consulta sql

Te voy a poner el ejemplo en mysql porque es lo que más manejo.

```
select * from tabla limit $offset, $limit;
```

Ejemplo página 1

Devuelve desde la fila 0 hasta un límite de 10 filas

```
select * from tabla limit 0, 10;
```

Ejemplo página 2

Devuelve desde la fila 10 hasta un límite de 10 filas

```
select * from tabla limit 10, 10;
```

Comment: Gracias Raúl! Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con Entity framework en el controlador backend en lugar de usar una sentencia SQL directamente?

Comment: Yo no manejo Entity Framework pero he hecho una búsqueda rápida y parece haber unas funciones para añadir al controlador que cumplen esta función. Te dejo un enlace para que lo revises. 

https://anthonychu.ca/post/entity-framework-parameterize-skip-take-queries-sql/

El método **Skip()** sería el equivalente a nuestro valor **offset** y el método **Take()** sería el equivalente a nuestro valor **limit**

Comment: Hola Raúl, si, yo he encontrado algo sobre skip también que estoy adaptando a mi código a ver qué tal, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!